# Slumdog millionaire (5)

Tags: knowledge, literature

My Indian friend Jamal recently participated in the well-known TV quiz
show ***[Who wants to be a millionaire?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who_Wants_to_Be_a_Millionaire)***. You might have heard or read about Jamal's spectacular success; the media reported on it extensively.

Here is what Jamal told us about his 1.000 Euro question:

> The first few answers I had rattled off with almost no pause, but the
>   fifth question (which would lead me to the first safe haven) took me quite a bit of thinking. I had heard of this author before, and I remembered a very negative newspaper article about him and all the "pseudo-religious" trash that he is producing. 
>   But I have not read any of his books, and in particular I hadve not read
>   *that* one, which apparently is his most famous one.
>
> I found the last answer rather unlikely. That guy surely was not Hannibal,
>   or was he?  Answer C on the other hand perhaps was a vague possibility.
>   But I knew that the author does not come from Argentina but from a neighboring country, and so this answer rather smelled like a trap. The first traps 
>   always pop up around the 1.000 Euro level. Answers A and B were similar 
>   in nature  and in appearance, one located in the north and one in the south 
>   of the continent. All in all I slowly started to build up an ever so slight
>   preference for answers A and B.
>
> At that moment I decided to simply use my "Ask the Audience" lifeline:
>   bestsellers, that's exactly what these guys should know about. The outcome
>   was very reassuring: 55 percent voted for A, 20 for D, 15 for B and only
>   10 for C. I picked A.  Is your decision final? Yes. Is this your 
>   final decision? Yes. Correct!

***What was the 1.000 Euro question?

What were the four possible answers A, B, C, D?***

Comment: how many question are there with you in this category... :)

Comment: I guess 15, as in the real TV show.

Comment: I thought this was about Carlos Castaneda but Peru doesn't border Argentina...dang it....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Question:

> **Where does Santiago, the protagonist of Paulo Coelho's bestseller "The Alchemist", decide to travel?**

Answers:

> **A** Sahara Desert
>  **B** Kalahari Desert
>  **C** Andes
>  **D** Alps

Answer (score 3):

I'm not quite there yet, but I think the question relates to

> Paul Coelho's book The Alchemist. 
>  Paul Coelho is Brazilian which is a neighbour of Argentina.

Something to do with...

> ...mountain ranges being crossed?
>  D: The Alps (Hannibal crossed the Alps).
>  A: The Atlas Mountains (the protagonist of The Alchemist crossed the Atlas mountains).
>  C: The Andes (which cross Argentina).

The only problem is I don't know which answer was B.

> There's nothing named similarly to the Atlas mountains in the South of Africa.